# Web3 - Assign nonce to smart contract transact

Tags: web3js, transactions, contract-design, remix, raw-transaction

I have a smart contract.
I want to execute one of its state modifying functions.

This is the code:

```js
const result = await smartContractObject.methods
    .addSomething(_valueToAdd)
    .send( { gas: '5000000', from:masterAccount });
```

How can I manually assign a nonce to this transaction?

Do I need to create a raw_tx?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure about modifying the nonce with `send` methods. 
You can use instead classic `web3.eth.sendTransaction` method (https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.1/web3-eth.html#sendtransaction). However, you'll need to provide the `data` field for this transaction.

```
const nonceThatIWant = x;
const txObject = smartContractObject.methods.addSomething(_valueToAdd);
const txData = txObject.encodeABI();
await web3.eth.sendTransaction({
   from:masterAccount,
   nonce: nonceThatIWant,
   data: txData,
   to: smartContractObject._address, //or smartContractObject.address depending on web3 version,

   //rest parameters like gas, value, gasPrice, etc.
});
```

Comment: Ok thanks for your help. However I need further assistance.
The smartContract emits a event. How do I receive this value now?


Originally it worked this way:
`result.events.myEvent.returnValues['myreturnvalue']`

Comment: use the resolved promise object's `logs` property. For example

`const result = await web3.eth.sendTransaction ....`

Then `result.logs` will contain all the events of transaction. The problem might be they have not very convenient format.